# (VBA) Excel : action if content in two columns is matching

Tags: vba, excel, match

A picture is worth a thousand words so to make it clear, here is a picture to illustrate the situation: 
[image]

So I have in a column C some contents (string and integer) from **C2** to **C16**.
I have another column G some city names (string) from **G21** to **G25**.

Here is what I try to do : I want my method probaCity() to look for matches between these two columns. If there is a match, I want it to display some value (10 for example) in the corresponding row of the G column (in the array "Probablity of being the city"), if no match, then it's gonna be 0.

So, here in the cell **G13** it should write 10 as there is a match for "Quezon" and 0 in all the other cells of the array.

Here is my code :

```
Sub probaCity()
Dim count As Integer, myResult As Boolean

For count = 2 To lastRow
Range("C" & count).Activate
myResult = IsNumeric(Application.Match(ActiveCell.Value, Range("G21:G25"), 0))

If myResult = True Then
Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value + 0
Else
Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value + 10
End If

Next count
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that myResult returned value is always false (so everything is set to 0 in my array).

Thanks a lot for your help.

**EDIT: after trying a suggestion** :
1/ Using VBA (working for everything but "Quezon")
[image]
2/ Using formulas... same issue.
[image]

Comment: have you even declared your lastRow?

Comment: Yeah, it's a global variable so it vas declared above, I know the problem is not from this as another method use it perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want my method probaCity() to look for matches between these two columns. If there is a match, I want it to display some value (10 for example) in the corresponding row of the G column (in the array "Probablity of being the city"), if no match, then it's gonna be 0.

No Need to use VBA for this.

See this example

Use this Array formula. You will have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> after entering the formula

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND($C$9:$C$11,A1)),"10","")
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**EDIT**: Since you want a VBA method, try this.

**VBA METHOD (this will work with the sample data as per your original post)**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LookUpRange As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> This is your city list
        Set LookUpRange = .Range("G21:G25")

        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            .Range("G" & i).Value = Application.Evaluate("=IF(COUNT(FIND(" & _
                                    LookUpRange.Address & _
                                    "," & .Range("C" & i).Address & ")),""10"",""0"")")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, good to know. I might use it if I'm still stuck with this problem later, but however I really would like to avoid using formulas like this, this is just an example but my final program should be much bigger and more complex. I think it would be clearer to use VBA for this matter. But thanks anyway, maybe I'll use this if my problem remains unsolved.

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't try it now but i will asap and mark your answer as the right one if it works!

Comment: : I tried, thanks a lot it's better now, but I have the weirdest thing happening. Whatever method I try (VBA or formulas), it's working for everything but the word "Quezon" (I added two screenshots in my first msg to illustrate). It doesn't make sense at all, why is this word treated differently excel? If it doesn't work for this one, how can I assume my program will be efficient (maybe some other cities will be "ignored" also) ?

Comment: I think it was just because of some "spaces", everything's fine now !

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this code is that myResult returned value is always false (so everything is set to 0 in my array).

Did you make sure that myResult is always false, or have you deduced it from the 0 values displayed?

Not sure if it will help, but `IsError` feels more natural than `IsNumeric` here. Your original If statement would be in the right order.

Comment: I tried with IsError instead, with "If myResult = True then" as well as with "If myResult then". Still 0 for every row or my G column. And I deduced from the 0 values return, concerning the false being returned.

Comment: I don't know if it's allowed to link another forum but there (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/915981-match-method-always-returns-false-comparing-cells-value-to-a-list.html?p=3202551#post3202551 ) I could add my excel file at the end of the first message. Maybe it could help !

Comment: debug.print(myResult) or msgbox(myResult) before your IF statements and see if it really always is False ( 0 )

Comment: I did, actually it's returning "true" for every line, and thus adding +10 to every row.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA.

1. Type formula `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(C2,$G$21:$G$25,0)),0,10)` into `G2`.
2. Copy `G2` to `G3:G17`.